# Where date('H') value comes from and what can affect it

Tags: php, html

I have a script that uses an if statemnt based on date('H')

```
if (date('H') >= 16) { do this}
```

98% of the time this works correctly.

On some submissions (date('H') > 16) it fails, if statment not fired.

Where does this value come from, is there anything from an individual users PC that can affect it?

I have tried modifying the system clock with no difference, no idea why some of these are failing.

Comment: It comes from the server clock, but is affected by your locale settings for timezone

Comment: that returns the hour in 24hour format with leading 0s so anything before 4pm will fail so before your server hits 4pm it will fail

Comment: Date('H') comes from server time not users pc times

Comment: It comes from the server time. [Here is the documentation for date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Yes, it will "fail" every day before 4pm (server time). What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: Might not have explained this well but I know everything before 4 will fail, the problem is that in some cases things after 4 are failing (if state,ment not fired) and trying to figure out what external factors may cause this (PC settings)

Comment: When all else fails, echo out the values, and check the time when it happens. It could just be a case of the timezone set.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
>   the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is
>   given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value
>   of time().

Well you could check with `time()` what value is currently handled.

Do to your problem:

Everything that is before 4pm will fail since the condition goes falsey.

Answer (score 0):

`date` outputs the current server time formatted in the timezone set by `date_default_timezone_set`. If you're getting unexpected values from it, you may be globally setting the timezone somewhere which changes the output:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('H');  // 15

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo date('H');  // 00
```